# Resize image with css not using crop method?

Tags: php, html, css

I want to resize image with css , But I couldnt.How can we do it?

```
<img class="img" style="width:200px;height:200px" src="<?php  echo $list[$i]->image; ?>"  alt="<?php echo $list[$i]->title ?>" title="<?php echo $list[$i]->title ?>" />
```

So I want to do width 200 and height 200 px , not image size.

Thanks.

Comment: so do you wanna crop the image using css or what's the problem here?

Comment: No I dont want to crop image.Ok I find the solution with css.With given style max-width,max-height. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can use it as a background and use the following properties:

```
background-repeat: no-repeat;
background-position: center center;
background-size: cover;
```

https://jsfiddle.net/alexndreazevedo/upn7jwfs/

Answer (score 0):

If you just want the image to be at max 200px width or high, you could do something like this:

```
<img class="img" style="max-width:200px;max-height:200px" src="<?php  echo $list[$i]->image; ?>"  alt="<?php echo $list[$i]->title ?>" title="<?php echo $list[$i]->title ?>" />
```

I changed `style="width:200px;height:200px"` to `style="max-width:200px;max-height:200px"`

If the image is not square the largest dimension will go to 200px and the other will scale to a smaller size.

Let me know if this doesn't make sense.